# How would I approach a question on using d'Alembert's solution to find the solution of the initial boundary problem?

Tags: wave-equation

[the question i am stuck on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFgn0.jpg)
I have obtained the following answers:
c = 2
f(x) = sin(3*x)*cos(6*t)
g(x) = 28*sin(7*x)*(cos(14*t))

however these don't appear to make sense with the boundary conditions. What is the correct way to approach a problem like this?

apologies i am new here so please bear with me as i learn the correct syntax